# MySQL Select data and manipulate

Tags: mysql

I have a table whose content like this :

[image]

If I use :

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(tgl_kecelakaan,'%M') AS NamaBulan,
    COUNT(DATE_FORMAT(tgl_kecelakaan,'%M')) AS total
FROM 
    tbl_kecelakaan_kapal
WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(tgl_kecelakaan,'%M')='January'
```

The result is : `January` `2`

But how to keep my query produces output like this (count all data) :

`January` `2`

`February` `1`

Without should I include `WHERE` condition as above ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(tgl_kecelakaan,'%M') AS NamaBulan,
    COUNT(1) AS total
FROM 
    tbl_kecelakaan_kapal
GROUP BY NamaBulan # or DATE_FORMAT(tgl_kecelakaan,'%M')
```